# Move a file to %appdata%\ngrokcraft doesnt work

Tags: c#, .net

If possible to help me. So here's the problem: I'm writing a project. and I got a problem every code I try. I have a option "Move server.jar to %appdata%\ngrokcraft% but it doesn't work.

```
string a = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string b = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
File.Move(a,b + "AppData\\ngrokcraft\\server.jar");
```

Can someone help me, also I would prefer answering in reply not comments. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetCurrentDirectory()` is the wrong place to start looking for `AppData`. Instead, look in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`.

```
string a = openFileDialog1.FileName;
string b = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
File.Move(a, Path.Combine(b, "ngrokcraft", "server.jar"));
```

Comment: May I suggest `Path.Combine(b, "ngrokcraft", "server.jar")`